# struts.xml how to replace the part path of <result>WEB-INF/account/ad_tools.jsp</result> wtih a variable

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, actionresult

Now I have the

```
<result name="success">WEB-INF/account/ad_tools.jsp</result>
```

which I want to replace the `WEB-INF/account` with something like this `{basePath}`, I can get

```
<resutl name="success">{basePath}/account/ad_tools.jsp</result>
```

I still can change the variable `basePath` when I need to.
Where should I put the variable `basePath` and How I can do it？
Or If you have another way to handle my question?

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to put this variable `basePath` to the value stack. You can do it in many ways. For example

```
ActionContext.getContext().getValueStack().set("basePath", "/WEB-INF/account");
```

The result attributes are parsed by default, so you can use it in the result declaration.

```
<result name="success">${basePath}/ad_tools.jsp</result>
```

Another way is to use convention plugin where you can define a constant

```
<constant name="struts.convention.result.path" value="/WEB-INF/account/"/>
```

and use annotation to override the convention configuration

```
@Result(name="success", location="ad_tools.jsp")
```

Comment: BaseAction  I add:
private String basePath = "WEB-INF/content";
public String getBasePath() {
    return basePath;
}
The conf file：
${basePath}/account/ad_tools_winfo.jsp
there is still 404 - /WEB-INF/account/ad_tools.jsp

Comment: I add "ActionContext.getContext().getValueStack().set("basePath", "/WEB-INF/account");" in BaseAction construts method.But it does not work,

Comment: What about the last option?

Comment: The convention plugin's path also didn't work or you don't know how to use it. If you are serious in Struts2 then convention is a must, you should use it.